# Help modeling a spear

Tags: modeling, 3d-printing

I need to model this spear but I'm not able to make the centre part because it's curved and I don't know how can do it. Can someone help me making this object?

it is relativity simple to make but I don't know how to proceed.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Essentially it seams a combination of various shapes.
A ballpoint shape (cylinder), and in the middle hollow sides fins.

I would start with 2 shapes, balpoint and fin.
Model them as best you can, then perform a boolean modifier to join them.
After that subdive the mesh, and smooth it out (maybe use the sculpt tools for fine tuning it all).

**P.S.** this website is for asking Question on how to do things with Blender, although sometimes people give a blend file as a way to show how something can be solved, its not a model sharing site such as blendswap.
**Note** you might also try the BlenderArtist Website forum where this is a payed and nonpayed section where artists create models for custommers.